# Add Image using FileStream and FileUpload

Tags: c#, filestream

I am trying to upload an image file to Server.MapPath("~/Pictures").  I believe The FileUpload has worked, I believe.  The FileStream has not put the image selected to "Pictures/".

```
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string imagename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
            string imagefile = Server.MapPath("Pictures/" + imagename + ext);
            byte[] Image = null;
            if (ext == ".jpg" | ext == ".gif" | ext == ".png" | ext == ".bmp")
            {
                Image = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
                HttpPostedFile UploadedImage = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                UploadedImage.InputStream.Read(Image, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
                int numBytesToRead = Image.Length;
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fsNew = new FileStream(imagefile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        fsNew.Write(Image, 0, numBytesToRead);
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException ioEx)
                {
                    Label100.Text = "Filestream Add Pictures: " + ioEx.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you checked permissions? If not, you should give permissions for that directory.

Comment: How? In Web.Config?

Comment: If you are working on web applicantion, you should give permission to IIS_IUSRS (for IIS) for file CRUD operations.

Comment: You can do it with using windows file explorer. Right click to folder -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> Add -> Advance -> Find -> double click IIS_IUSRS and continue.

Comment: Nothing happened after adding IIS_IURS. Just working in IIS Express.